# How took Com objects that are in WCF project to the server

Tags: c#, wcf

I published WCF service to the server it is working locally but in the server I am getting this error:

```
 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID.
```

The job of the service is adding some fields to word template and convert it to pdf. My guess is that it can not find com object in the server. one of the object that I reference in my project is

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

I have added this as a reference to my project what should I do to install this object in the server?

Comment: Have you got Word installed on the server? Interop won't work without it http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/469105/Microsoft-Office-Interop-Word

Comment: Install word manually

Comment: @Alma see my updated answer, I added example code after you accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` is not designed [to be run in a non interactive session](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) (for example in a self hosted service or IIS, the two ways you would host WCF on a server). Even if you do get your code to run you are going to start running in to other issues as listed in the above link.

You will need to switch to the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to be able to manipulate word documents in a server setting.

**EDIT:** While not directly related see [this old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490493/using-sharepoint-word-automation-to-do-a-text-replace) where I was making the same mistake as you  (Using Word automation to do a text replace inside a Sharepoint web service). In the answer I posted to my own question I have some example code of how to replace text using the Open XML SDK.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentStream, true))
{
    template.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = template.MainDocumentPart;
    mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart.AddExternalRelationship(
        "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate",
        new Uri(templetAddr, UriKind.Absolute));

    ReplaceText(mainPart, "#PracticeName#", PracticeName);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EducationDate))
        ReplaceText(mainPart, "#EducationDate#", EducationDate);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MainContactInfo))
        ReplaceText(mainPart, "#MainContactInfo#", MainContactInfo);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
        ReplaceText(mainPart, "#Address#", Address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been faced to this problem couple years ago, in Visual Studio - project properties/in the Build tab:

set the platform target = `X86`

and let me know if worked.

Comment: actually that was the only solution that I have found but it did't work for me:(

Comment: :( , check this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/638130/Retrieving-the-COM-Class-Factory-for-Component-w

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Office automation using Word Interop is not good approach and OpenXML is the way to go. But since it is very complex, my recommendation would be to look at 3rd party toolkits which use OpenXML. This way you don't have to spend time learning OpenXML.

Try to search for "mail merge and reporting toolkit". Ideally, template documents should be designed or changed by using MS Word, even by end users. The toolkit should be simple to use with intuitive APIs.