# asp.net Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, office-interop

I am trying to get rid of empty pages that merge when the users views and prints the document. I am using the Dev express editor so the user inserts text that make the page over flow to other page (rtf) and creats an empty space. any way to stop this from happening>?

here my code:

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Drawing.Imaging;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Xml;
     using System.Xml.Linq;
     using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;


     using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
     using WordApplication = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;


     namespace DocumentMapper
     {
     public class XmlDocumentMapper
     {
    /// <summary>
    /// Use to replace all text elements included in template text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mergeDocInfo"></param>
    /// <param name="html"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string MergeHtml(MergeDocInfo mergeDocInfo, string html)
    {
        return MergeText(mergeDocInfo.MergeValues, html);
    }

    public static string MergeHtml(Dictionary<string, string> mergeValues, string html)
    {
        return MergeText(mergeValues, html);
    }

    public static string MergeHtml(MergeDocInfo mergeDocInfo)
    {
        string htmlText = null;
        string template = string.Format("{0}{1}", mergeDocInfo.TemplatePath, mergeDocInfo.TemplateName.Replace(".docx", ".html"));
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(template, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                htmlText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return MergeText(mergeDocInfo.MergeValues, htmlText);
    }

    public static void SearchAndReplace(MergeDocInfo mergeDocInfo)
    {
        string template = string.Format("{0}{1}", mergeDocInfo.TemplatePath, mergeDocInfo.TemplateName);
        string document = string.Format("{0}{1}", mergeDocInfo.MergeDocPath, mergeDocInfo.MergeDocName);
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(template, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordTemplate = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, false))
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(document, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            foreach (var part in wordTemplate.Parts)
                wordDocument.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId);

            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordTemplate.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            docText = MergeText(mergeDocInfo.MergeValues, docText);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
            }
        }

        FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(document);
        FileInfo mergeFile = new FileInfo(document.Replace(".docx", ".pdf"));

        DoIt(tempFile, mergeFile);
    }

    private static string MergeText(Dictionary<string, string> mergeValues, string text)
    {
        var dateValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in mergeValues)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(pair.Value, out dt))
            {
                dateValues.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dateValues)
        {
            mergeValues[pair.Key] = DateTime.Parse(pair.Value).ToShortDateString();
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in mergeValues)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Key))
            {
                text = new Regex(pair.Key).Replace(text, string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Value) ? "_____" : pair.Value);
            }
        }

        return text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obsolete
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tempFile"></param>
    /// <param name="mergeFile"></param>
    private static void DoIt(FileInfo tempFile, FileInfo mergeFile)
    {
        WordApplication word = new WordApplication()
        {
            Visible = false,
            ScreenUpdating = false
        };

        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object filename = (Object)tempFile.FullName;

        Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        doc.Activate();

        object outputFileName = (Object)mergeFile.FullName;
        object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

        doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
            ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
        ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        doc = null;

        ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        word = null;

        tempFile.Delete();
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: Microsoft strongly recommends against using Office automation (and therefore Word Interop) on the server.  Before going into anything else, I would suggest refactoring to remove the automation code from any server -related processes, perhaps by receiving user requests and running the automation offline to be sent to the user later.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Answer (score 0):

[Office interop is not supported from non user sessions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) (For example from a ASP.NET service), this may explain the strange behavior you are seeing.

You need to switch to a supported solution for manipulating documents from a non user session like the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) before you attempt to correct any other problems.

**UPDATE:** re-reading your question, you are already using Open XML (the code in `SearchAndReplace` is already using it) you just need to replace the code in `DoIt` to use Open XML too.

Comment: is switching from interop office to open xml sdk a long process?

Comment: It will require you to rewrite some of your code but it is not too hard. See [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490493/using-sharepoint-word-automation-to-do-a-text-replace/5491122#5491122) for a example of what word replace code looks like (The answer is for sharepoint instead of ASP.NET but you can get the basic gist of it, just look at the part inside the `using (WordprocessingDocument ...` block, that is the Open XML part)

Comment: HOLD UP!!, re-reading your question, you are already using Open XML (see the `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;`), you just need to replace the code in `DoIt` to use Open XML instead of the office interop.